# Zero-count bins in simulating binomial fluctuations of histograms in R

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I have a histogram with observed bin counts.  I would like to run simulations based on the observed counts to see how the same number of observations might have happened differently.  I turn the histogram into a vector with the observed counts as an element of the vector.  I simulate each bin using random numbers generated from binomial distributions (from `rbinom(n, size, prob)`) with probabilities based on bin frequencies.

My problem is simulating bins with zero observed counts.  When the bin count is zero, `prob`=0, so the simulated count for that bin is always zero.  This is non-physical and not what I want.  At present, I deal with the problem by overriding zero bin counts with bin counts of 1.  I'm not sure of the effect of this is, so I don't know if I'm biasing my simulation beyond my tolerances.  I'm looking for a better or more elegant solution to the problem than my ad hoc method.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

Here's my relevant code:

```
sim.vector <- function(x, n = length(x)) {
  sum.vector <- round(sum(x), 0)  # the number of observations
  x.dummy <- x
  x.dummy[x.dummy == 0] <- 1  # override bins with zero counts
  f <- x.dummy / sum(x) # the frequency of each bin
  x.sim <- rep(0, n)
  while(sum.vector != sum(x.sim)) {  # make sure the simulation has the same
                                     # number of total counts as the observation
    for (i in 1:n) {
      p.target <- f[i]  # set the probability of each bin to the frequency
      x.sim[i] <- rbinom(1, sum.vector, p.target)  # create a random binomial
    }
  }
  return(x.sim)
}
```

Comment: How many bins (`n`) are there? I should guess 2, but you never know. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand very well, but try this: `sample.int(n, size = sum(x), replace = TRUE, prob = f)` and see if it takes you somewhere.

Comment: `n` can be any integer.  Typically for the simulations I'm doing it's between 2 and 6.

Comment: `sample.int` looks interesting;  I've never used it before.  I'm not sure if I understand it correctly.  For my situation, say I'm flipping a coin. `x` is the vector of results, say, `x <- c(4, 6)` so there are 4 heads and 6 tails.  I want to use `f <- c(0.4, 0.6)` as the base probabilities to see what range of counts is possible.  When both bins are non-zero, it's a straight-forward binomial problem where each simulated heads count is `rbinom(1, 10, 0.4)`.  The problem comes when there are zero observed heads.  The "true" probability is non-zero, but `rbinom` will always produce 0.

Comment: Thanks for the `sample.int` pointer.  It definitely speeds things up by avoiding the `while` and the `for` loops I had.  I can now use `x.sim <- sample.int(6, size=sum.vector, replace=TRUE, prob=f)`.

I am still, however, left with the problem of zero-count bins, as the probability weights will remain zero for the empty bins.  I can override the weights with a small but non-zero amount, but that's the scenario I started with.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do sounds a lot like bootstrapping, where if you start with an array of n values, you take n randomly chosen values from that array with replacements.  As you've noticed, bootstrapping won't give you a value that you don't already have.

You're method of setting zero bins is OK.  One technique that ecologists use is to set zero values to the minimum measurement error that they could make.  For example, if counting trees, the minimum miscount would be 1.  If keeping the mean value of the distribution is important to you, make sure that changing 0 to 1 didn't increase the mean too much.

Another option is to fit your bins with a parametric distribution.  Do people in your field have a typical distribution that they use or does the data suggest a distribution?  If you still need bins, you can bin the fitted parametric distribution.  Good luck.

Here's a faster way to generate your bin counts:

```
# you have three bins which we label 1,2,3
# change to 1:n where n = number of your bins
binIndex = 1:3
# you have 2 values in bin 1, 3 values in bin 2, 1 value in bin 3
count1 = c(2,3,1)

# create a vector with all bin labels
unbin = mapply(function(bin1,ct1){
    rep(bin1,times=ct1)
},binIndex,count1)

unbin = unlist(unbin)
print(unbin)

# generate "bootstrapBinCount" of bootstrapped bins
bootstrapBinCount = 10

# in general, use lapply instead of while/for loops in R - it's orders of magnitude faster
# newBins is a list of binCounts
# to access the first bin count, try newBins[[1]]
newBins = lapply(1:bootstrapBinCount,function(x){
    # generate a bootstrap from the list of bin labels by sampling with replacement
    bootstrap1 = sample(unbin, size=length(unbin), replace = TRUE)
    # count the number of times each bin label shows up
    rebin = table(bootstrap1)
    # get the names of the labels that showed up
    names1 = as.integer(names(rebin))
    # fill in the counts from rebin, but also include cases where there are no values     for a given bin label
    rebinPlusZeroes = rep(0,times=length(binIndex))
    rebinPlusZeroes[names1] = as.integer(rebin)

    return(rebinPlusZeroes)
})

print(str(newBins))
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem of addressing zero counts in frequency estimation is sometimes called smoothing (particularly in the natural language processing community, where they deal with thousands of "bins" and so zero counts are common); instead of using counts, you use [pseudocounts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocount).

One simple approach similar to what you're doing is called [Laplace's "rule of succession"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession): just add one to each bin (not only the zeros). More generally, you can add a different number (typically less than one) in [additive smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing). Bayesian-ly, this corresponds to using a Dirichlet prior on the binomial probabilities.

A more sophisticated approach is [Good-Turing smoothing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good-Turing_smoothing).

If you have a different probabilistic model for your data that makes more sense in your setting, you can also use that (as suggested by Eric).